# pass form variables using commas

Tags: php, jquery, forms

i'm having multiple results,which have json data placed in it and i have placed compare button to compare all these results together,on button click it passes the variables in url like

[image]

```
http://localhost/course/compare_results.php?course_id=1&course_id=2
```

i want my url should pass data as: `http://localhost/course/compare_results.php?course_id=1,2`.

**EDIT: Adding Code **
My Code for ajax call is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".compare").change(function() {
if(this.checked) {  
  $('#compare_box').show();
var check = $(this).val();      
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'compare.php',
        dataType : "JSON",
        data:{value : check},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);

       var output = "<div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style='float:left'>";
       output += "<div id='course_title' class='well well-sm'>";
       output += "<h4>"+data.title+"</h4>";
       output+="<textarea class='hidden' id='hidden_title' name='course_title' value=>"+data.title+"</textarea>";
        output+="</div>";
        output+="<input type='hidden' id='hidden_id' name='course_id' value="+data.id+">";
       output+="</div>";
            $('#result').append(output); 
        }
    });
  }
   else if(!this.checked && boxes[check]) {
boxes[check].remove();
delete boxes[check];
  }
 });
});
```

php code is:

```
<div id='compare_box'>
    <form action="compare_results.php" method="GET">
                <?php ##include 'compare_template.php'; ?>

      <div id='result'>

      </div>
      <button id="compare_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">compare</button>
      </form>
        </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left"> 

        <div class="well well-sm">

        <h4><small><?php echo $title; ?></small></h4>
       </a>
     <br>
     <input type ='checkbox' name="compare" class="compare" value="<?php echo $id;?>">add to compare
     </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What you really should do is pass like `course_id[]=1&course_id[]=2`

Comment: Use jquery or javascript to make your url on click event.

Please provide your code to get more specific answer.

Comment: Yeah, please provide existing code that you've tried. We're not solution monkeys dancing to your beat

Comment: use explode() to getting query in array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the data in the query string in a variable, you can get the data into a string.

If you want to convert it into array (which is more suitable for data processing), you can use PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) built-in function.

Here is the example:

```
<?php
// course/compare_results.php
$courses = $_GET['course_id'];
var_dump($courses);

$arr = explode(',', $courses);
var_dump($arr);
```

When you visit the link in your browser: http://localhost/course/compare_results.php?course_id=1,2

Then, the result will be like below.

```
string '1,2' (length=3)

array (size=2)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
```